# Making Matrices without a library / Inserting nested lists without anything being in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, arraylist

*I am trying to input and then print a matrix in Python without a library.*

#### Code:

```
a = []
n = int(input('Length of the row'))
m = int(input('Length of the column'))
for j in range(0, m):
    a[j].append([])
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, m):
        a[i][j] = int(input())

for i in range(0, n):
    print()
    for j in range(0, m):
        print(a[i][j], end=" ")
```

#### Working:

When I put my list to be let's say:

```
a = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
```

And put both *m* and *n* to be ***3***, It works exactly as it should.

#### Error:

But having only an empty list, as in the code example, I always get an error that list index is out of range.

```
a[j].append([]) IndexError: list index out of range
```

#### Problem:

I don't know how to input nested lists inside a list, and integers inside those nested lists, with a loop, or with anything for that matter.

Comment: Where do you get the error and what is the error's exact text?

Comment: a[j].append([])
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bound to fail:

```
a = []
# ...
for j in range(0, m):
    a[j].append([])  # a is empty, so a[j] must fail!
```

Try instead:

```
a = []
n = int(input('Length of the row'))
m = int(input('Length of the column'))
for i in range(m):  # m is len of outer list: number of rows == len of column
    a.append([])
    for j in range(n):  # n is len of inner list (those are the rows)
        a[i].append(int(input()))  
        # append as well, as indexes to fill do not exist yet

# the loop could be written as a comprehension:
a = [[int(input()) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]

for i in range(m):
    print()
    for j in range(n):
        print(a[i][j], end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first loop and then make the input loop look something like this:

```
a = [None] * n
for i in range(n):
    a[i] = []
    for j in range(m):
        a[i].append(int(input()))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you *create* `a` it is empty so you cannot not index anything in it.

```
>>> a = []
>>> len(a)
0
>>> a[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#126>", line 1, in <module>
    a[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Just append the empty lists:

```
>>> a.append([])
>>> a
[[]]
>>> len(a)
1
>>> a[0]
[]
>>>
```

You have a similar problem when adding to the inner loops. It could be done like this

```
>>> i = 0
>>> a[i].append(int(input()))
4
>>> a
[[4]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`append` will add elements to a list. `a` is empty at firsts so `a[i]` is an error. See my sample that does what you want.

```
a = []
n = int(input('Enter row count: '))
m = int(input('Enter column count: '))
for i in range(0, n):
    a.append([])
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, m):
        a[i].append(int(input()))


for i in range(0, n):
    print()
    for j in range(0, m):
        print(a[i][j], end=" ")
print()
```

Sample run:

```
Enter row count: 2
Enter column count: 3
1
2
3
4
5
6

1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You have **two** mistakes:

1. You are not being consistent on what are rows and what columns
2. You are addressing an array/list content that hasn't been allocated any memory

Furthermore, you don't need that third for loop.

```
n=2
m=3
a=[]
for i in range(0, n):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(0, m):
        a[i].append( int(input()) )
print(a)
```

which, for input 1-6, gives you

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```